# Adding Images to react-native stack navitagion tab view footer

Tags: react-native

I want to add some images instead of vector icons in my react native footer. It Tried to do it but the images are not displayed as expected. Here is my code. How can I achieve this? ClickableIcon is a custom component.I want to replace Vector Icon  with my custom ClickableIcon component

```
import React from "react";
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from "react-navigation";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import { ClickableIcon } from "../mixing/UI";
import { MainFeedActive, MainFeedInactive } from "../config/images";

import {
  MainFeedScreen,
  WorkoutScreen,
  ProfilePageScreen,
  VideosScreen,
  ChatScreen
} from "../screens";

export const TabNavFooter = TabNavigator(
  {
    mainfeed: { screen: MainFeedScreen },
    workout: { screen: WorkoutScreen },
    videos: { screen: VideosScreen },
    chat: { screen: ChatScreen },
    profile: { screen: ProfilePageScreen }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        // let iconName;
        // if (routeName === "mainfeed") {
        //   iconName = `home${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        // } else if (routeName === "workout") {
        //   iconName = `shield${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        // } else if (routeName === "videos") {
        //   iconName = `television`;
        // } else if (routeName === "chat") {
        //   iconName = `message${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        // } else if (routeName === "profile") {
        //   iconName = `account${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        // }

        let imageSource;
        if (routeName === "mainfeed") {
          // imageSource = `home${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
          imageSource = { MainFeedActive };
        } else if (routeName === "workout") {
          imageSource = `shield${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "videos") {
          imageSource = `television`;
        } else if (routeName === "chat") {
          imageSource = `message${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "profile") {
          imageSource = `account${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        }
        <ClickableIcon source={imageSource} />;

        // return <Icon name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      }
    }),
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "blue",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray"
    },
    swipeEnabled: false,
    lazyLoad: true,
    animationEnabled: false
  }
);
```

Comment: You say that your images are not displayed as expected. How do they look when you use the  code you pasted?

Comment: The images are empty. Nothing is shown. But they are clickable and functioning when I click on the places where the images should be.